# Moving homepage to subfolder without affecting seo

Tags: seo, 301-redirect

I have website that focus in first time in negociation techniques. I have invested a lot to make homepage well ranked on Google. Now I want to make site bigger. I want to extend it to be about everything about soft skills.

How to tell google that the home page that was targetting keyword "negotiation techniques" is now in url : exemple.com/negotiation_techniques and that home page now target "soft skills" ?

Comment: It is often a mistake to target your hike page for keywords our than your brand name. I'd create new pages for both negotiation and soft skills.